# PHP Mailing List Regex

Tags: php, regex

i'm creating a PHP Mailing List System.
what i need is regexing some character for the name, email, etc.
For Example

---

Hi, [[FirstName]]

blablabla

Regards, Jeff

---

And the regex should detect the [[]], the FirstName and replace it with some string from DB.

I'm not regex expert, i've tried some regex but can't make the perfect solution..

Thanks..

Comment: Why aren't you using `str_replace` ?

Comment: `\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/5lB89Y/1

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll simply use str_replace. And thanks for the regex, will be usefull someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use `str_replace`.

> mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )

Source: [PHP: str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Your code could look like this (if `$text` contains the mail-text):

```
$text = str_replace("[[FirstName]]", "Name 1", $text);
```

---

If you want to replace multiple strings at once you can use arrays for `$search` and `$replace`

```
$text = str_replace(array("[[FirstName]]", "[[LastName]]"), array("Name 1", "Name 2"), $text);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right... my mind stuck on regex. I forgot regex is for non-fixed string. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

You dont need Regex for what you want, if you have fixed variables. All you need is str_replace(). Put the Variables of your Template in the first Array and the Values from the Data-Source in the second Array().

Example:

```
$message = str_replace(array('{name}', '{whatever}'), array($name, $whatever), $message);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.